# general idempotent matrix possible values of the determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant, idempotents

If A is a general idempotent matrix, calculate the possible values of det (A)

I caculated the det = o what other values can it equal?

Answer (score 5):

An Idempotent matrix is one for which $A^{2}=A$, hence $\text{det}A^{2}=\text{det}A$. whence,
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{det}A^{2}-\text{det}A &=& 0 \\
\implies\text{det}A(\text{det}A-1) &=& 0
\end{eqnarray}
From which it is readily obvious. Note, one of those conditions implies the existence of an inverse...